# How to specify the distributable directory visible for both NPM and TypeScript? (Multiple files case)

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

The library written in TypeScript includes three main files for distribution:

- `NodeJS.js` - for, obviously, Node.js runtime.
- `BroswerJS.js` - for, obviously, browser runtime.
- `index.js` - common functionality for both browser and Node.js

[image]

There no "main" file in this library so I has not specified this property in `package.json`.

Planning usage:

- `import { isUndefined, isNull } from "package-name;`
- `import { delegateClickEventHandling } from "package-name/BrowserJS;`
- `import { NodeJS_Timer } from "package-name/NodeJS;`

Currently, the TypeScript with below config compiles files below `Source` directory to `Distributable` directory:

[image]

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,

    "removeComments": true,

    "outDir": "Distributable/",
    "declaration": true
  },

  "include": [ "Source/**/*" ]
}
```

If to publish the library such as, TypeScript even will not see it:

```
import { isUndefined } from "package-name";
```

```
TS2307: Cannot find module 'package-name' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Because as default TypeScript expecting that `.d.ts` files will be in root directory of the library. But the distributables are in `Distributable` directory!

And of course, `isUndefined` will not be found. I know about `"main"` property in `package.json`, but it is for one file case, but what about directory?

I know that multiple distributable files exporting is the supported scenario. For example the [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) exporting `promise.ts` besides `index.js`:

```js
import MySQL from "mysql2";
import MySQL_Promise from "mysql2/promise";
```

### Update

The NPM part solved - modern solution is `exports` filed in `package.json`:

```
"exports": {
  ".": "./Distributable/index.js",
  "./NodeJS": "./Distributable/NodeJS.js",
  "./BrowserJS": "./Distributable/BrowserJS.js"
},
```

But distribution files are still invisible for TypeScript.

```
TS2307: Cannot find module 'package-name' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I learned about [`"types"` field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) of package.json. Unfortunately, it could be only a string. It means currently it's impossible to specify multiple files. The [issue about making in to array](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6585) has been declined.

But how to make visible all of `"./Distributable/index.js"`, `"./Distributable/NodeJS.js"`, `"./Distributable/BrowserJS.js"` for TypeScript?

Please don't suggest me again to make all imports to single entry point. In this question we considering the multiple entry points case.

Comment: The `main` file should include all the exports you want to use `from 'package-name'`

Comment: @Matt, Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, it's impossible because some functionality is for BroswerJS only and some functionality is NodeJS only.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#version-selection-with-typesversions.  In package json you can add "typesVersions": {
    "\*": {
"NodeJS" : [ "Distributable/NodeJS.d.ts" ],
      "BrowserJS": [ "Distributable/BrowserJS.d.ts" ],
      "\*": [ "Distributable/*" ]
    }
  }

Answer (score -1):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achive, in TS generally when you have single project with 1 configuration file, and you emit multiple files from it, you would not use package name within the same project, use path instead './someFileName'.

If you have multiple projects (tsconfig files) to manage different directories - sort of monorepo thing going on.

Your best options is project references: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html

Or if you are doing something else then this may help altho I'd do this as last resort :-)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths